# Столкновение с твёрдым объектом

Tags: c#, monogame

Есть у меня два объекта, у которых имеется свой `Rectangle`
Как проверить что они столкнулись я знаю:

```
if(obj1.rect.Intersects(obj2.rect))
{
    ...
}
```

Теперь мне нужно сделать, чтобы при столкновении первый объект останавливался, как если бы упёрся в стенку
Допустим, у меня 2 прямоугольника, мне нужно просто проверять с какой стороны произошло столкновение?
Пробовал делать так:

```
if(obj1.rect.Intersects(obj2.rect))
{
    if(obj1.Position.X >= obj2.rect.Width - obj2.Position.X)
        obj1.Position.X -= obj1.Speed;
}
```

Но при столкновении `obj1` всё равно немного проходит сквозь `obj2`
Как сделать, чтобы `obj1` сразу же упирался в `obj2`?

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так. Не тестировал, но идея должна быть понятна:

```
if (obj1.rect.Intersects(obj2.rect))
{
    // Используем функцию Intersect из System.Drawing, которой нет в Monogame.
    var overlap = System.Drawing.Rectangle.Intersect(
        new System.Drawing.Rectangle(obj1.Position.X, obj1.Position.Y, obj1.rect.Width, obj1.rect.Height),
        new System.Drawing.Rectangle(obj2.Position.X, obj2.Position.Y, obj2.rect.Width, obj2.rect.Height)
        );

    if (overlap.Width < overlap.Height) 
    {
        // По оси X нужен меньший скачок, будем двигать по ней.

        if (obj1.Speed.X > 0) // obj1 движется вправо
            obj1.Position.X = obj2.Position.X - obj1.rect.Width;
        else                  // obj1 движется влево
            obj1.Position.X = obj2.Position.X + obj2.rect.Width;
    }
    else
    {
        // Будем двигать по оси Y.

        if (obj1.Speed.Y > 0) // obj1 движется вниз
            obj1.Position.Y = obj2.Position.Y - obj1.rect.Height;
        else                  // obj1 движется вверх
            obj1.Position.Y = obj2.Position.Y + obj2.rect.Height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вариант неплохой, но что если `Speed` - обычная переменная?

Comment: Тогда нужно смотреть на вектор скорости. Чем он задается?